How would you write this modified version of the ring inscription in the Black Speech?

One ring to rule you, one ring to find you
One ring to bring you, and in the darkness bind you
I love you
Gopinadh


The only things Tolkien ever wrote in Black Speech were the ring inscription, a single further sentence, and some five further words. Except for "them" in the ring inscription, no pronouns are known, and neither is the verb "love". So, this is impossible to translate.

Is your sweetheart a masochist?

I guess if Black Speech had the verb “to love”, it would have only the meaning “to eat eagerly” or  “to consider edible”.

Black Speech is mostly reconstructed, and there are different versions of it. This is my attempt at translating it, using the Shadowlandian dialect -- the beginning is mainly the standard Ring motto, but with the object pronoun changed to 3rd person singular (instead of plural).

One ring to rule you,

Ash nazg durbatlat,

one ring to find you,

ash nazg gimbatlat,

One ring to bring you,

ash nazg thrakatlat,

and in the darkness bind you;

agh burzumishi krimpatlat.

I love you Gopinadh

Brogbizg lat, Gopinadh
I hope this is useful!

"Reconstructed" doesn't really seem accurate seeing as a huge number of the morphemes here are entirely absent in Tolkien's writings. Instead Neo-Black-Speech is a conlang distinct from but consistent with Tolkien's Black Speech sketch

also should that read: "Brogbizglat" instead of "Brogbizg lat"?

@Tristan Yes, "reconstructed" is doing a lot of heavy lifting here... there are various versions that are kind of extrapolated from the few attested Black Speech sentences. The separation of lat is arbitrary; it could also be all separate: izg brogb lat; So yes, brogbizglat would also be possible.

the other instances of an 2sg object pronoun have it written joined to the verb though, so having it separated seems somewhat inconsistent (although ofc that is the only finite verb, whereas the others are infinitive, and ofc languages can distinguish in how they treat object pronoun clitics between finite and non-finite verbs, just as Spanish does e.g. finite "te amo" vs infinitive "amarte")
